# python 3 flashing text limited times

Tags: python

Hi guys I want to make a text in a label to flash 6-7 times when a condition is met. I have read several topics on the internet but still struggle. I made it up to the point where the text blinks constantly but can't figure out how to stop it after 6-7 blinks.

Here is the code I am using:

```
def flasher():
    current_color = A.cget("fg")
    next_color = "green" if current_color == "red" else "red"
    A.config(fg=next_color)
    root.after(1000, flasher)
```

This is what I have found.

```
def flash(self,count):
    bg = self.cget('background')
    fg = self.cget('foreground')
    self.configure(background=fg,foreground=bg)
    count +=1
    if (count < 31):
         self.after(1000,self.flash, count)
```

I could not make the above code to work but I assume it is alternating the colours of `fg` and `bg` but I need only the text to change colour.

I want to somehow implement `count` to the the first code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it. Here is the code if someone needs it.

```
count = 0


def flasher():
    global count
    count += 1
    current_color = A.cget("fg")
    next_color = "green" if current_color == "red" else "red"
    A.config(fg=next_color)
    if count < 10:
        root.after(1000, flasher)
    else:
        count = 0
```

It is working exactly as I want it to. Just `count < 10:` should be an even number. Otherwise it will stop blinking with `next_color`(green) and if you run it twice it will stop with the starting one (red).